# Getting Array length is 0 instead of correct length

Tags: angular

I am getting array length is 0, but I should return correct length value.

```
      data[];
      count: number;
      blog(){
      this.blogService.getBlog().subscribe(                    
        res=>this.data=res
        this.count=this.data.length 
        //this length value getting 0, but      actually it has length value 4
       )}
```

API response is,

```
    [ {
      "title": "xxxx",
       "body": "yyyy"
     }, {
       "title": "aaaa",
        "body": "bbbb"
     },  {
       "title": "cccc",
       "body": "dddd"
     } ]
```

Comment: Can you please mention what type of data you are getting. Is that array of string/inter Or array of Object.

Comment: Please show `res` value

Comment: Please provide the blog service API response with the question.

Comment: Added in my post.. pls check

Comment: Note that `this.data` is not that `data`  you've defined in first line because `this` refers to `subscribe`. define $this = this; outside of your method and then in your method do like this: `$this.data=res`

Comment: Without executable code no one can help you. Try to make a executable code

Comment: Are you returning the data correctly as an Observable from getBlog()?

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed out a curly braces after `res =>` . Can you try this ?

```
   this.blogService.getBlog().subscribe(res => {              
     this.data=res
     this.count=this.data.length 
   })
```

Comment: It would throw an error if the posted code was actually run without curly braces, I believe the posted code is just a quickly written sample

Answer (score 0):

Check if the response is actually an array and not array like object.
Run below snippet in chrome devtools console-

```
var arr = [];
arr['k1'] = 100;
console.log(arr); //o/p - [k1: 100]
console.log(arr.length); ///o/p- 0
```

Fix -> Make sure the array is properly used on the server side.

1. If pushing object use `arr.push({'k1': 100})` instead of `arr['k1'] = 100`
2. If you are restricted to do changes in server-side than use below snippet in client side.

   ```
    var arr = [];
    arr['k1'] = 100;
    var dataObj = {...arr};
   ```

Comment: Yes getting the same

Comment: To fix it make sure on the server-side the array is used properly. Like if want to push objects, then do arr.push({'k1': 100}).
Please do not forget to upvote my answer. Thanks :)